# to_wait_duration with boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

The Boost Asio `basic_waitable_timer` class (also included in the C++ Networking TS), takes a template parameter [**`WaitTraits`**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/wait_traits.html), which allows for custom behavior in terms of converting `duration` and `time_point` values into wait durations.

Specifically, a `WaitTraits` class is expected to have two overloads of [**`to_wait_duration`**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/wait_traits/to_wait_duration.html).  The overload that takes a `time_point` is expected to convert it to a `duration` value that makes sense for a wait duration value that may be passed to an OS wait/sleep function.

The default implementation, `wait_traits<Clock>`, is implemented here:

https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/include/boost/asio/wait_traits.hpp

However, looking at the actual source code of the default implementation, I can't make any sense of what `to_wait_duration` is actually doing.  Here is the code:

```
  static typename Clock::duration to_wait_duration(
      const typename Clock::time_point& t)
  {
    typename Clock::time_point now = Clock::now();
    if (now + (Clock::duration::max)() < t)
      return (Clock::duration::max)();
    if (now + (Clock::duration::min)() > t)
      return (Clock::duration::min)();
    return t - now;
  }
```

I get that the idea here is to take a `time_point` and convert it to a `duration` value that will likely be passed to some OS wait function.  So the obvious way to do that would be to just return `t - Clock::now()`.  Of course, you may also want to do things like check for overflow.

But what this implementation seems to do makes no sense to me.  Firstly, wouldn't the expression `now + Clock::duration::max()` *always* cause a signed integer overflow - thus triggering undefined behavior?? (Assuming that `Clock::duration::rep` is a signed integral type, which it would be for standard `chrono::duration` types).  Secondly, I can't tell what this function is trying to achieve.  Why does it ever return `Clock::duration::min()`, which would usually be a negative value?

I would think that a `to_wait_duration` function would simply do something like check if `t > Clock::now()`, and if not, just return `Clock::duration::zero()` (since a negative wait duration never makes sense).  Basically, something like:

```
   static typename Clock::duration to_wait_duration(const typename Clock::time_point& t)
   {
     const typename Clock::time_point now = Clock::now();
     return (t > now) ? (t - now) : Clock::duration::zero();
   }
```

But... what the actual Boost source code is doing is very confusing to me.  What does the Boost implementation of default `wait_traits` actually do?